# Android - Rotate Admob view 90 degrees?

Tags: android, admob

I have been working 2 days to make Admob view displays vertically on my landscape game, the problem seemed to be straightforward, just rotate the view 90 degrees. The first try was to call setRotation(90), I had a crash on my 2.3.4 device because the method is not available untill Android 11. The second try was to use rotation animation, the view did rotate but it get clipped to its original bounds and furthermore it accepts touches as if it was not rotated :(. Finally I found a way to solve the clipped view problem, just call setLayoutParams(width, height) - with width and height large enought, on all the child view of admob view. The problem of touches still unresolved :)
I'm very frustrated, why Android needs a very complex solution for a very simple problem ? In iOS, I just need to apply a rotation transformation to the view and nothing more !
Please help me !
Any suggestion are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 90, admobView.getWidth() / 2,     admobView.getHeight() / 2);
rotate.setDuration(500);
rotate.setRepeatCount(0);
rotate.setFillAfter(true);
admobView.startAnimation(rotate);
```

Comment: I did try this, but after rotated admobView accepts touch as if it was not rotated. In addition, admobView.getWidth() and     admobView.getHeight() sometimes return 0.